# No attribute "rotation_euler" on a KX_GameObject?

Tags: python, game-engine

To begin, here's my code:

```
import bge
from bge import logic
import random
from math import degrees

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
rotation = own.worldOrientation.to_euler()
rotation_x_round = round(degrees(rotation.x), 3)
rotation_y_round = round(degrees(rotation.y), 3)
rotation_z_round = round(degrees(rotation.z), 3)
own["x"] = rotation_x_round
own["y"] = rotation_y_round
own["z"] = rotation_z_round

own.rotation_euler = Euler((10, 10, 10), "XYZ")
```

I am trying to set the rotation of my object, not add rotation. In the code, `own.rotation_euler` is what creates the error. It is telling me there is no attribute "rotation_euler," so I tried changing the line to the following: `own.worldOrientation = (10, 10, 10)`. This one works; however, as I've assumed, it didn't rotate it correctly as it rotated the object to a number which seemed independent of my input. I have come up with my code from [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31702/how-to-set-objects-rotation-from-python) question. Why does Blender's rotation_euler not work? Thanks!

Also, the .blend (that you can use as a start) can be found [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/39666).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Details

A [KX_GameObject](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject) has no attribute called "rotation_euler".

What you request for is [KX_GameObject.worldOrientation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.worldOrientation) or [KX_GameObject.localOrientation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.localOrientation) as you mentioned in your question description.

Be aware the orientation is a 3x3 matrix. The setter accepts [Euler](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/mathutils.html#mathutils.Euler) and a 3-tuple with Euler coordinates for your convenience. It will automatically convert it to a 3x3 matrix.

I'm pretty sure your observation of

> [...] it rotated the object to a number which seemed independent of my input.

is not correct.

## Answer

You answered your question by yourself: `own.worldOrientation = (10, 10, 10)`.

## Remarks:

- A [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) does not deal with angles, it is a linear equation system. It is a [Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system). You will never be able to directly read any angles from it. But you can convert the coordinates to a different coordinate system e.g. polar coordinates via [mathutils'](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.to_euler) `Matrix.to_euler(order, euler_compat)`.
- Euler coordinates are angles given in rad (not degree). It is a [Polar coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).
- The value 10rad will automatically reduced to the first period of the [radian angle measure system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian)'s range (-pi ... +pi) which is -2.5664rad or -147°.
- To convert degree to radian you can use the python library [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) e.g. `math.radian`

Comment: No problem, I removed the reference to the old question

Comment: cool will remove the comment :)

Comment: "You answered your question by yourself: own.worldOrientation = (10, 10, 10)." I am a bit confused. I looked up for some information about the orientation, the "3x3 matrix." I couldn't come up with a solution. I was trying to *set* the object's rotation to 10, 10, 10. I am not sure how it is coming up with -32.958... Again, this could be because I am not familiar with the orientation. Could you explain a little? I'd greatly appreciate it. And as always, thank you for the answer! :)

Comment: I added some more details. Does that help you more?

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. It helped me a lot. It cleared up a lot about what I've been confused about, especially the links. I have finally come up with a conclusion. It has 2 parts, here's part 1: eul = mathutils.Euler((math.radians(10), math.radians(10), math.radians(10)), "XYZ"). Also, here's where the rotation takes place (part 2): own.localOrientation = eul.to_matrix(). Thank you for the information! :)